# Highcharts linechart slow transition when div changes

Tags: highcharts, vuejs3

I am using highcharts with Vue 3 wrapper.
Trying to render a div in the same row with my linecharts. The other div (the one with red border) renderes/un-renders when clicking on "Show/Hide chat history button"

[image]

```
      trendGraphOptions: {
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        point: {
          events:{
            select: (event) => {
              let date = event.target.category
              let value = event.target.y
              alert('click' + date + value) 
            }
          }
        },

        states: {
          hover: {
                lineWidthPlus: 0, // Adjust the line width on hover
                lineOpacity: 1, // Set the line opacity on hover
                halo: {
                    size: 9,
                    attributes: {
                        fill: '#9731FF',
                        'stroke-width': 2,
                        stroke: '#9731FF'
                    }
                }

            },

            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }
}

    },

    chart:{
      height: "20%",
      type: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x',
      resetZoomButton: {
          position: {
              // align: 'right', // by default
              // verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
              x: 0,
              y: -30
          }
    }
    },
    credits: false, // can add credits in bottom right
    title: {
      text: '',
      align: 'center',
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSize: '1.3rem',
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: '#181819',
        margin:'5px'
      },
    },

    xAxis: {
      tickInterval: 5,
      categories: [],
      offset: 10,

    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: null,
      labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return this.value.toFixed(2); // Set the number of decimal places you want
      }
    },
      crossHair: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickWidth: 1,
        title: {
            align: 'high',
            offset: 0,
            rotation: 0,
            y: -10
        }

      },
      
    
    series: [

    ]
  },
  spectrumGraphOptions: {
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        point: {
          events:{
            select: (event) => {
              let date = event.target.category
              let value = event.target.y
              alert('click' + date + value) 
            }
          }
        },

        states: {
          hover: {
                lineWidthPlus: 0, // Adjust the line width on hover
                lineOpacity: 1, // Set the line opacity on hover
            },

            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }
}

    },

    chart:{
      type: 'line',
      height: "30%",
      zoomType: 'x',
      resetZoomButton: {
          position: {
              // align: 'right', // by default
              // verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
              x: 0,
              y: 0
          }
    }
    },
    credits: false, // can add credits in bottom right
    title: {
      text: '',
      align: 'left',
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif',
        fontSize: '1.3rem',
        fontWeight: '600',
        color: '#181819',
        margin:'5px'
      },
    },

    xAxis: {
      tickInterval: 100,
      tickPosition: 'inside', // Place the ticks inside the plot area
      categories: [],
      offset: 10,

    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: null,
      labels: {
    },
      crossHair: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickWidth: 1,
        title: {
            align: 'high',
            offset: 0,
            rotation: 0,
            y: -10
        }

    },
    tooltip: {
      animation: false,
      useHTML: true,
      headerFormat: '<table><tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; !important;"><th colspan="2">{series.name}</th></tr>',
      pointFormat:
        '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">M(x): </td>' +
        '<td style="text-align: left">{point.x} Hz</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">M(y): </td>' +
        '<td style="text-align: left">{point.y} mm/s</td></tr>',

      footerFormat: '</table>',
      valueDecimals: 2,
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
      
    
    series: [

    ]
  }
```

My problem is when the div renders (clicked on "show chat history"), the transition is slow, and when I hide the div the transition is faster.

**Video**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9XcMjGdejY

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with the Highcharts library? Are you able to reproduce this in an online editor: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-newton-j5j9ft?